# How to populate a data report row by row

Tags: vb6, report, record

I have to change a very old application written in Vb6 with Data Report.
Actually displays a query records with only one field named txtdata.

Now I would display always one field (txtdata) but with different text size and style depending on whether it starts with a # or not.

I thought to check records for records if it starts with # or not and set text style and size for each record.

How can I do?

```
 Dim rs As Adodb.Recordset
 Dim sql As String
 Dim regtratt As  
 .................
 ' I have a Data Report with textbox named txtdata in Section1  
 sql = ""
 sql = sql + "SELECT txtdata "
 sql = sql + "FROM journal "
 sql = sql + "WHERE cod=421 "
 sql = sql + "ORDER BY id "

 Set rs = xOpenRecordset(sql, cnOnline)
 If rs.RecordCount > 0 Then

    Set regtratt.DataSource = rs
        regtratt.DataMember = ""

    ' I want to change the font according to the text but I don't know how to because DataSource=rs takes the records.                         
        'If InStr("#", regtratt.Sections("Section1").Controls(1).Item.Value) Then
        '    regtratt.Sections("Section1").Controls(1).Font.size = 20
        '    regtratt.Sections("Section1").Controls(1).Font.Bold = True
        'End If

      regtratt.Orientation = rptOrientLandscape
      regtratt.WindowState = vbMaximized
      regtratt.Font.Name = "courier new"
      regtratt.Refresh
      regtratt.Show vbModal
      Unload regtratt

 Else
      MsgBox ("Sorry No data")

 End If
```

Comment: please add an example and what you have tried to far

Comment: I added the code in the first post.